# Copy and Paste Special on two spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro for a simple copy and paste Special for one of my projects.

Just to break it down.

1. I have two excel Spreadsheet(HK Maintenance BAU) and (Sample Macro Sheet)
2. I need to copy and paste special from HK Maintenance BAU to Sample Macro Sheet
3. I would love to copy to the latest cell that is empty.

Below is the code, however I am only able to copy and paste but could not be paste special.

Any response would be appreciate. I am a newbie to VBA. Appreciate and many thanks once again.

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iLastCellS2 As Excel.Range
    Dim iLastRowS1 As Long

    Set s1 = Sheets("HK Maintenance BAU")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sample Macro Sheet")

    'get last row number of J in HK Maintance BAU Sheet'
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    'get last AVAILABLE cell to paste into'
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    'copy&paste into Sample Macro Sheet'
    s1.Range("G1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "G")).Copy iLastCellS2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) out. Should help you on your way.

Comment: @Peter Hi, Where should I change ? I tried different ways but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
'copy&paste into Sample Macro Sheet'
s1.Range("G1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "G")).Copy iLastCellS2
```

into this:

```
'copy&paste into Sample Macro Sheet'
    s1.Range("G1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "G")).Copy
    iLastCellS2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Then you are able to use other options for `xlPasteValues` as you need